# consume Asp.net MVC api from android volley

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, android-volley

i am trying to consume a MVC 4 api from my android application 
i am using Volley library and it work fine to get data from server 
the problem is when i try to send data to the web service which i understand it should be done by using post Method and JsonObjectRequest

my method in MVC Api is :

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
 public IEnumerable<string> Post(List<string> val)
        {

            return val;
        }
}
```

and for volley :

```
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("email", "S@b.Com");
    params.put("username", "basheq");
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST , 
    AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new JSONObject(params),new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + jsonObject.toString());
            }
        }
      , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_string_req);
```

but i keep getting null in response and it look like the api doesn't parse the parameter . 
what is wrong ?? , and is this the proper way to do it or is there a better way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that i was setting list as a parameter which for some reason does not work 
the solution was by wrapping the input parameter into a class and of course change the json structure to correspond to that